# Unable to save,please resolve the merge conflicts in the project file before attempting to save further changes"

Tags: svn, jdeveloper

i checked out an application from svn plugin of jdeveloper and tried to modify the same and save it.Got an error Unable to save,please resolve the merge conflicts in the project file before attempting to save further changes"
i tried mergin,updating,commiting the file but still the error doesn't go.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue which you are facing now. This issue related to library files (Jar files) location. 
My colleague shared the project with me, I have opened that project using my IDE, then this error has been thrown. Because I don't have the jar files in my local machine in the same path where he has mentioned.

EX: In his machine, saved all jars under **C:\XXX\YYY** folder and map that path to libraries. But I don't have those jars in that path.

*Resolution*: I just changed the jar files path and pointed to the folder where I have Jar files in my system.

Answer (score 0):

The merge conflict means there are text in the files specified with the following code

```
<<<<<<< .mine

=======
>>>>>>>
```

You need to remove those text and resolve on what you want the final code to be between the above marked texts. That fixed our merge conflict issue in JDeveloper's .jpr file.